# SQLite ordering that puts prefix matches first

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I was wondering how I might formulate a SQLite ORDER that as its first criterion will separate matches depending on whether a search string was matches against a prefix or an infix of a column. The second ordering would be simply ASC.

E.g. searching for "st" and simply ordering by that column will yield:

- Astrophysicists
- Baker Street
- Master Yoda
- Stack Overflow
- Star Trek
- Stegosaurus
- System Shock
- Westwood

I'd like to order it like this:

- Stack Overflow
- Star Trek
- Stegosaurus
- Astrophysicists
- Baker Street
- Master Yoda
- System Shock
- Westwood

So prefix matches come first, then the rest. The secondary ordering is simply ASC.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a Table named **Products** and let us just make it simple that it has only one field named **Productname**. And you want to search a Product name that starts with the word **Co** or has the word **Co in between**.

So, the query would be like this:

```
SELECT Productname FROM Products
WHERE Productname LIKE 'Co%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Productname FROM (
SELECT Productname FROM Products
WHERE Productname LIKE '%Co%'
ORDER BY Productname) B
```

So, if you have the following records

```
Coco Crunch
Lucky Cow
Coffee
Sweet Corn
Cookies
Corn Puff
```

It would now become like this

```
Coco Crunch
Coffee
Cookies
Corn Puff
Lucky Cow
Sweet Corn
```

Try it out with your own fields and Table.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, this does not filter out any records that don't contain the search string at all. But using your sample I might get that working myself.

Comment: @Chris I edited it that it would now match your requirement hopefully.